# How can I make TextBox Change Event filter GridView pointed to SQL Server?

Tags: vb.net

I have the code below which works for MS Access.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox1.Click

    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Northwind_2012.mdb"
    Dim selectCommand As String
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)


    selectCommand = "Select * From MyExcelTable where Fname Like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
    Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection)

    With DataGridView1
        .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
    End With

    Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

    Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
    Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table

    Dim data As New DataSet()

    data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
    Me.DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    Me.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)

End Sub
```

I want to do the same thing, but point to a SQL Server query, and not an Access query.  Does anyone know how to do that?  If so, please do share.

Comment: Have you tried with SQL Server?  What happens?  For the most part the NET DBProviders all work the same.  You do know the `TextChanged` fires every time they press a key, right?

Comment: The code will be almost exactly the same.  The only change will be using `SqlClient` types instead of `OleDb` types. It would have taken very little research to find that out. That said, you should also parameterise your query. Using Access, the worst that can happen with that code is your app may crash. Using SQL Server, which supports multiple statements per command, a malicious user could delete every record in your database.

Comment: Depending on how much data you have, it may also be a better idea to retrieve all the data upfront and then filter via a `BindingSource`. That avoids going back to the data all the time and possibly retrieving the same data over and over.

Comment: It's also a bad ideas to filter on the `TextChanged` event. Let's say that the user wants to match "abcd". Typing that in will raise four `TextChanged` events and you will query the database four times and get the same data multiple times too. It's better to use a `Timer` that you reset on a `TextChanged` event. That way, if the user enters multiple characters fairly quickly, you'll avoid extra filters. Something like half a second is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

With some light testing, the script below seems to work as desired.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=NORTHWND")
        con.Open()
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Categories", con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Cat")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Cat")

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        ds.Tables("Cat").DefaultView.RowFilter = "[CategoryName] LIKE '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*'"
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'll look into that timer option tomorrow.  That's very clever!  Thanks for the tip!!